# Core plot - plotting long dates and integers

Tags: ios, objective-c, plot, timestamp, core-plot

I'm trying to plot some data, timestamp vs result out of 10.

Example of data:

```
1390834893 = 2;
1391111518 = 8;
1391111519 = 8;
1392498193 = 5;
```

I've been playing with CPTPlotRange to try and get the scale on the x axis correct:

```
CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [CPTMutablePlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromString(@"0.0") length:CPTDecimalFromDouble([[goalResults objectForKey:@"latest"] integerValue] - [[goalResults objectForKey:@"earliest"] integerValue])];
```

or

```
CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [CPTMutablePlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble([[goalResults objectForKey:@"earliest"] integerValue]) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble([[goalResults objectForKey:@"latest"] integerValue])];
```

Unfortunately this causes the phone CPU and memory usage to sky rocket and crash.

I have had some success with:

```
CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [CPTMutablePlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromString(@"0.0") length:CPTDecimalFromString(@"20.0")];
```

But this will not be good once more data has been added.

With plotting timestamps, what is the best way to plot them given potentially years between plots?

Edit: I'm also adjusting the plots to be (latest - earliest) / 10000 or so with the way I'm currently doing it.

Answer (score 1):

What labeling policy are you using on the x-axis? If using the default (fixed interval), be sure to increase the `majorIntervalLength`. The default of one (1) will cause the axis to create ticks and labels one unit apart. With the range you listed, that's over 1.6 million labels.

Comment: It's on 10, I increased it to 10000 and 100000 and either the graph doesn't show correctly or it maxes out the cpu.

Comment: Be sure to set the `majorIntervalLength` during the initial setup or at the same time you set the large `xRange`. Once the graph has a chance to draw, it will try to create the labels.